# How to convert an integer to a uint8_t pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, formatting

I have a function defined like:

```
void foo(uint8_t *val, int num)
{
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
        printf("Buffer[%i]=0x%X \n",i,val[i]);
}
```

As a global variable, I have an array declared as:

```
uint8_t Buffer[4] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04};
```

So in order to print the buffer, I do the following:

```
int main()
{
    foo(Buffer,4);
    return 0;
}
```

Which gives as a result:

```
Buffer[0]=0x1                                                                                    
Buffer[1]=0x2                                                                                               
Buffer[2]=0x3                                                                                               
Buffer[3]=0x4
```

The thing is that, for a particular case, I need to send only one uint8_t parameter to that function replacing the buffer, so I implemented it like:

```
int main()
{
    uint8_t READ_VAL[] = {0x01};
    foo(READ_VAL,1);
    return 0;
}
```

Anyway, is there any way to do it inline? I tried to do it like

```
foo((uint8_t *)0x01,1);
```

but it is not working (gives me Segmentation fault error). Any idea how can I do it?

Comment: What you seem to seek is called [*compound literals*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

Comment: If you only have 1 value why not replace the function call with the printf directly?

Comment: I just reduced my case to this simple printf case to reproduce my problem, but in reality it is not an option. @Lundin

Comment: Indeed, that is really what I needed. Thanks! @some-programmer-dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo((uint8_t []) { 0x01 }, 1);
```

The form “`(` *type* `) {` *initializers*… `}`” is a *compound literal*, specified in C 2018 6.5.2.5. It creates an object of the specified type with the value given by the initializers.

`(uint8_t []) { 0x01 }` creates an array of one `uint8_t` with value `0x01`. As an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, which is suitable for the first parameter of `foo`.

A compound literal inside a function is temporary, with automatic storage duration associated with its enclosing block. A compound literal outside a function endures for the execution of the program, with static storage duration.